# Laravel8 storage files not found

Tags: laravel, deployment, storage, laravel-artisan

`php artisan storage:link`

local worked fine.
After deployment without start `php artisan serve` it doesnt find the files in storage.
Symlink is online.

Comment: What's the error showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok if I make symlink on my own it worked fine.

use
`ln -s ../storage/app/public storage`

instead of
`php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to ssh or to the remote terminal:

```
php artisan storage:link
php artisan config:clear
```